# How to remove used endpoints when running flask application using virtual env

Tags: python, flask, foreman

I have a view python file which has the code:

```
@app.route('/')
def index():
  page = """
  <html>
  <head>
  </head>
  .....
  ...
  </html>
```

I made some changes to this file , those just normal changes like importing `render_template`.I was able to see the html file using foreman start command in my `localhost`. However after some changes as I mentioned earlier , when I again start using foreman start I get an error - `" View function mapping is overwriting an existing endpoint function: index "`

However when I used `@app.route('/',endpoint ="new")`, it worked.

Looks like it reserving some endpoints and not letting me override it. How can I remove all the endpoints to start fresh.

Comment: Can you share the entire file where you define this view?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you don't have two routes with the same URI.